# How to deduce the formula for the $k$-th derivative of logarithm function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Given $\ln'(t) = \frac{1}{t}$. How Can we deduce the formula for the $k$-th derivative: $\ln^{(k)}(t) = \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!}{t^k}$ for $k \geq 1$.
I know how to prove this using induction, but how can just deduce this formula from the first derivative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By letting the $n$th derivative be denoted by the function
$$f_n(x)=(\ln{(x)})^{(n)}\text{ with } f_0(x)=\ln{(x)}$$
We have that
$$f_1(x)=x^{-1}$$
and every function following $f_1(x)$ is produced by multiplying the previous function by the current power and reducing the power by one. So we must have that
$$f_n(x)=a_nx^{-n}$$
Where the constant terms $a_n$ are given by the recurrence relation
$$a_1=1$$
$$a_n=-(n-1)a_{n-1}$$
This can easily be solved by noticing
$$\begin{align}
a_n
&=-(n-1)a_{n-1}\\
&=(-(n-1))(-(n-2))a_{n-2}\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)(n-2)\dots a_1\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!\\
\end{align}$$
So the functions are given by
$$f_n(x)=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!x^{-n}$$

Comment: Yes, but to justify the steps used here, you need to use induction.

Comment: Where is the inductive step? Noticing that $n!=n(n-1)\dots1$ does not seem to require induction to me.

Comment: "every function following $f_1(x)$ is produced by multiplying the previous function by the current power and reducing the power by one. So we must have that $f_n(x) = a_nx^{-n}$" - while this is intuitively obvious to see, this claim requires induction to rigorously prove

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with any definition of the $k$-th derivative that is not itself inductive.  Therefore, naively you would need to use induction to derive any formula for the $k$-th derivative.

However, we might be able to get tricky, if you allow the use of the following properties:

- $\ln(x)$ is the inverse function of $e^x$.
- For all $k \in \Bbb N$, if $f(x) = e^x$, then $f^{(k)}(x) = e^x$.
- The Taylor series for $e^x$ is $\sum \frac{x^m}{m!}$.